# Bootstrap loader and operating system

Tags: operating-system, bootstrapping

Does operating system remove the bootstrap loader from primary memory after operating system is loaded?Once operating system is loaded is it the ultimate authority of primary memory?(like it decides what programs will occupy which space in memory?)

Answer (score 1):

Some operating systems may preserve the boostrapping code in the same way most preserve BIOS code. As for Linux and Windows, they indeed mark the memory previously occupied by the bootstrapping code as unallocated and will use it in any way they find appropriate. The code won't actually be removed but will be overwritten once the OS allocates this memory region.

Comment: Can you provide some GitHub source code proof of what you say the OS does?

Comment: You can see reserved memory in Linux in `/proc/iomem`. Bootstrapping code is loaded to 0x7c00 and GRUB loads stage2 to 0x8000. Both addresses are in a region marked as System RAM (`00001000-0009e7ff : System RAM` on my computer) which means it is used for programs and data.